# When should we use stored procedure instead of function in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, stored-procedures

As I am not so clear in scenarios of when to use stored procedures instead of functions ,

I have a scenario where a function is already being used, but as it takes much time to execute in a stored procedure, now can I replace this function (which returns a string) with a procedure?

Can any one please explain me what happens when replacing a function with a stored procedure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magically performance boost from either one. If they contain the same code, they'll have the same performance.

I'd say, keep it as a function unless or until you reach a limitation of functions - e.g. if you want to actually change database state.

Functions are more composable - you can call them directly from within other statements such as `SELECT` - whereas stored procedures have to be explicitly called.

Comment: But in my scenario this function is taking 500,000 lines at once as input and could not execute faster, how should i control the flow or increase performance.

Comment: @Pink - examine the execution plan, consider adding appropriate indexes. There's no magic wand.

Comment: Indexes to tables which are used in functions?

Comment: Can i divide output lines into different slots and supply it to functions? is that possible?

Comment: The system will automatically parallelize a plan if it believes that it would be beneficial to do so.